# How to allocate space to std function and do memcpy?

Tags: c++

I have the following piece of code.

```
void functionName(std::function<void()> &&lambda){
  void* h = (void *)malloc(sizeof(lambda));
  memcpy(h,lambda, sizeof(lambda));
  performTask(&h);
}
```

performTask will take the address and run the lambda function.
But I'm not able to do memcpy as the second arguments in memcpy has to be const void*.

So I modified my memcpy to memcpy(h,(void*)&lambda, sizeof(lambda)); 
Although it compiles successfully, during run it throws segfault.

How to properly do memcpy in this code scenario?

Comment: Also what are you actually trying to do here? What do you think using `memcpy` on a `std::function` will give you?

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: Are you interested in lambdas specifically, or `std::function`? They're not the same.

Comment: If I directly pass my lambda expression to performTask() which might not fit the space(as there can be a recursive call to the same function again). And I need to find a way to pass that and hence I'm doing malloc.

Comment: `(as there can be a recursive call to the same function again)` why should that change the size in anyway? Labdas or what ever the `std::function` is pointing to  is compiled code that is evaluated by the CPU. Copying a lambda or `std::function` does not copy or generate any new compiled code. What might/will increase is the memory allocation on the stack, but that it not related to memory allocated by `malloc` on the heap.

Comment: Functions running on the heap will still allocate their local variables on the stack. You aren't saving anything this way. In fact you are increasing the stack usage by putting an additional pointer on the stack to point to your copy.

Comment: My advice is to forget about `malloc` and `memcpy`. Very few programmers every actually need them.

Answer (score 3):

First of all `std::function` is not a lambda it's a class template for wrapping all kinds of callable objects **including lambdas**.

Secondly you should never try to `malloc` and especially `memcpy` non-POD C++ types. They have their own set of constructors/assignment operators that provide the means for copying them properly. For example:

```
void functionName(std::function<void()> &&lambda) {
  auto h = new std::function<void()>(std::move(lambda));
  performTask(h);
  delete h; //assuming that performTask isn't asynchronous
}
```

---

To answer the motivation you gave in comments about recursion: this is probably the wrong way to go about it. If you think that the depth of your recursion might overflow the stack then you should try to rewrite your algorithm using loops instead. Trying to save stack space by moving local variables to the heap is likely only a temporary solution if it gives you any results at all.